# Iterator calls all elements at once within an each block

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I build the array here:

```
  def initialize
    @names = []
  end

@names << page.all('//*[@id="USERS_AVAIL"]/option').map {|result| result.text.split(", ")}
```

later on I'm trying to compile and visit url's by iterating through the names array like so:

```
@names.each do |name|
                  visit "https://example.com/k=#{name}&tpe=1"
end
```

Some puts statements show me that the each method is calling every element of the array all at once instead of iterating as intended. I.E.: `"https://example.com/k=#{[[%22Adviento%22,%20%22Justin%22],%20[%22Asamoah%22,%20%22Nathan%22],%20[%22Baughman%22,%20%22Zachary%22],}&tpe=1"`. @names.length has a count of only 4 but a puts of the @names array shows the proper output? I'm not sure what could be wrong, thanks in advance for any assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<<` with `+=`. The `<<` is inserting *the entire array* as a single element of its own, whereas `+=` will concatenate the array, which seems to be your intention.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
# => [1, 2, 3]
a << [4,5,6]
# => [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]] # WRONG

a = [1,2,3]
# => [1, 2, 3]
a += [4,5,6]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # CORRECT
```

---

Try:

```
@names += page.all('//*[@id="USERS_AVAIL"]/option')
          .map { |r| r.text.split(',').map(&:strip) }.flatten
```

---

If the quotes are in the literal form `%22` and you want to capture the strings in between them:

```
@names += page.all('//*[@id="USERS_AVAIL"]/option')
          .map { |r| r.text.scan(/%22([^%]+)%22/) }.flatten
```

Comment: Duhh, that easy huh? I feel silly, and you get your checkmark in 4 mins when SO will let me. Thanks again.

Comment: @jcuwaz No problem; it's always good to wait to vote, as we never know what interesting insight or suggestion someone else may have.

Comment: Update: this is still just using the paired element instead of the split. Now the first index is: [%22Adviento%22,%20%22Justin%22] I would like it to only be "Adviento" and the second index "Justin"; is something wrong with my split in the capture stage?

Comment: plus a few gsubs your update works exactly as I intended